# Javascript doesn't fire

Tags: javascript

Im using this code on checkout so that if someone selects Michigan as there State then a link will show to get tax exempt paperwork. However, the console is giving me an error that a closing parenthesis is missing. I don't see it.

```
    function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != "loading"){
    fn();
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
  } else {
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function() {
      if (document.readyState != "loading")
        {fn();
    }
  }
);

ready(function() {if(document.getElementById("pay-with-po")){
   document.querySelector("select[name="region_id"]").onchange = function(){
     if (document.querySelector("select[name="region_id"]").value==33){
          alert("MICHIGAN!!!"); //or another action to display a div/title etc...
     }
   }
 }});
```

Comment: A good IDE should be able to point out where for you.

Comment: It would help spotting mismatched parenthesis if you indented your code properly!

Comment: "find my mismatched brackets" is a poor question.  "How can I easily spot them" might be better.  Fortunately a few folks have answered #2 in the comments.

Comment: As others have stated, format your code correctly. [Here's how I would format your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/utmezkcr/) Two errors are relatively obvious when you follow proper indentation. Likewise, the error should give you a line number you can check.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem here:

```
  if (document.readyState != "loading")
    {fn();
    ^ This one is open and not closed
}
```

Comment: ready func has `);` instead of last `}` too

Comment: indentation and good ide will solve his problems, and i'm 99% sure he has more errors somewhere else in his code, but this is a start.

Comment: Questions like these should be closed as typographical problems with perhaps a small comment leading OP to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState != "loading") {
        fn();
    } else if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function () {
            if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
        })
    }
}

ready(function() {
    if(document.getElementById("pay-with-po")){
       document.querySelector('select[name="region_id"]').onchange = function(){
         if (document.querySelector('select[name="region_id"]').value==33){
              alert("MICHIGAN!!!"); //or another action to display a div/title etc...
         }
       }
 }});
```

This should be ok.